Bulk transaction on Base chain
After adding liquidity, I frequently see wallets making bulk transactions on the base chain. How can I snipe tokens early and cheaply like them?
CA: 0x1234567517769aCd8519BA85184EdbBaC6062971
Tx: https://basescan.org/tx/0x1d5fcab20e2c75577ba5ffcda798bcc588851215d1fc8e738f74d959210cac4e



Sniping tokens can be tempting, but it's high-risk (volatility, scams) and often technical (bots). Consider safer strategies: research projects, use established exchanges, focus on long-term value.
